# Any advantages when using an ORM Tool (Framework)?

Tags: orm, ado.net

I searched over .... I see many advantages, but it seems that all the advantages comes from a comparison over in-line SQL. I know in-line SQL is bad. But why compare with a bad one to show the other better?

If stored procedures are used (possibly exclusively), it seems none of the advantages still exists. Stored procedures definitely provide performance advantages in terms of security, performance (If a ORM can outrun a stored procedure, then the stored procedure is badly written) and a well written stored procedure is an automatic repository (pattern). Stored procedures can definitely provide better transaction and transaction isolation control.

I really appreciate an answer -- how ORM is better over a well architected application using stored procedures.

---

--- Thanks for all the answers that I receive so far ... It seems that the advantages still come from comparing using ORM's "dynamically generated SQL" with using "statically written in-line SQL" in the code. Yes, it has advantages. But it is not he question.

The question is better stated as the following:

If you consider having the stored procedures to implement your business logic (SPs can be written very advanced, and also very efficiently), in the Application code (.NET, JAVA), you have a very thin layer wrapper of the stored procedures organized by business need. My question is how ORM out-perform this architecture (Of course a well designed one).

Comment: I don't see how an ORM is necessarily orthogonal to SPROCs. SPROCs define an action-oriented-interface, but ORMs (even those which don't try to force OO concepts on a relational model) focus on exposing the data in a model other than a table -- e.g. a list of well-defined tuples (or objects). Some ORMs will allow using the appropriate SPROC actions while others shun SPROCs entirely. So ... "it depends".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORM Tools make possible to develop abstraction layer between database and the model in the OO environment. The main advantage of this layer is that the developers who are not familiar with SQL can work with the model.

Comment: It is not necessarily because that the software engineers are not familiar with SQL. I suddenly realized that in a lot of places, in-line SQL is still the data access method used in developing applications. In these places, ORM tool is surely superb. Yes. The conclusion that ORM is advantageous is a result of comparing it with in-line SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I have been seeking a good answer myself. Here is what I feel makes the difference:

1) ORM increases the developer productivity - mapping domain class to database is easier.
2) Stored Procs can potentially contain business logic - it is difficult to test these. This is mainly because of lack of tools/mocking framework.
3) ORM frameworks are tested ones which give you features like caching out of the box - no need to reinvent the wheel - and in most applications I've seen which do not use any ORM feature end up writing in-house Data Layer which ORM offers out of the box.

That being said - ORM does add some overhead as well, and it requires the developers to be aware of a new platform - writing efficient mapping comes with practise so there is a learning curve.

In the modern day setup, network bandwidth isn't as precious as rapid development and good quality (well tested) code. I guess this makes ORM well suited for database driven apps.

Answer (score 0):

An ORM is a tool that can be used to build what you call a "well architected system". The idea is that when you are developing in a non-Relational language, there will be an [impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) between the relational operation set provided by SQL/Stored Procedures and the language that you are using to build the rest of your application.

For developers using an object-oriented language (whether it is C++, C#, or Java) there are many considerations when mapping a complex relational schema into a rich Domain Model. It is certainly possible to perform all of this mapping in your own code, but as  your interactions in this "no-man's-land" between OO and Relational paradigms grow more complex the more useful an ORM engine and associated tooling can be.

Some considerations as you plan out your mapping layer:

- Do you need manage single-table or multi-table inheritance?
- Do you want to leverage lazy loading?
- Do you want to manually keep classes and tables synchronized or are you planning on using a tool to generate per-table classes (such as with a `DataSet`)?

Another consideration, especially when working in a team, is that when relational to domain layer mapping is performed by hand, there can be a great deal of variation in the way developers write the mapping. This can lead to inconsistencies, overlapping, and gaps that are difficult to detect. The selection of an ORM  (especially a well known / solidly established ORM) can have an enormous (hopefully positive) impact on the solution and the pre-existing community surrounding that ORM will shape how you conceive of the mapping layer (you will find that there are significant cultural differences between Spring.NET and Entity Framework users, for instance).

Does an ORM make a good architecture? No. Are there systems whose architectures would be better off with an ORM? definitely. Are there projects that have been crippled by the unnecessary addition of an ORM? I'm guessing that there are many.

I suggest approaching this question from a different angle, and apply it to the specific application you are working on. Do you have any pain points by using SQL and/or Stored Procedures that an ORM might solve? Do you see any risks or have any concerns over problems that the introduction of an ORM might cause? Only by weighing the answers to these questions will you be able to determine if an ORM is a good fit for any given solution.

Comment: Honestly. In the real world many applications, I never encounter a problem that "Stored Procedures" have difficulty to solve.